# Why won't groupby properly sum across level of index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('111222'),
        B=list('xyzxyz'),
        C=range(6)
    ))

d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('111222'),
        B=list('xyzxyz'),
        C=range(6)
    ))
```

I want to concatenate these and perform a `groupby`

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index('A') for d in [d1, d2]], keys=['d1', 'd2'])
print(df)

      B  C
   A      
d1 1  x  0
   1  y  1
   1  z  2
   2  x  3
   2  y  4
   2  z  5
d2 1  x  0
   1  y  1
   1  z  2
   2  x  3
   2  y  4
   2  z  5
```

However, when I do a `groupby` and `sum`

```
df.groupby(level='A').C.sum()

A
1     0
1     2
1     4
2     6
2     8
2    10
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Which isn't at all what I was expecting.

I can take apart `df` and piece it back together again then perform the `groupby`...
I expected this

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values,
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.values, names=df.index.names),
    df.columns.values
).groupby(level='A').C.sum()

A
1     6
2    24
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug. Making your index a `MultiIndex` is a small hack that works

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index(['A', [np.nan]*len(d))]) for d in [d1, d2]], keys=['d1', 'd2'])
```

Another solution would be to reverse one of the `DataFrames`

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index(['A']) for d in [d1, d2.sort_index(ascending=False)]], 
               keys=['d1', 'd2'])
```

Specifically, in concatenation of dataframes with same index which is non-multiIndex with specification of keys, the new `MultiIndex` that is created gets the labels `0,...,len(d)` without relation to the original labels. (If you look in the index, you see that you get several copies of each label with different id).

Specifically, it is due to the following piece of code in [`pandas.core.reshape.concat`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py)

```
def _make_concat_multiindex(indexes, keys, levels=None, names=None):
    ...   
    ...  # Somewhere here we treat the non identical axis
    ...
    if isinstance(new_index, MultiIndex):
        new_levels.extend(new_index.levels)
        new_labels.extend([np.tile(lab, kpieces) for lab in new_index.labels])
    else:
        new_levels.append(new_index)
        new_labels.append(np.tile(np.arange(n), kpieces))
```

So, if the index is not multi-index already, the labels assigned are `np.arange(n)`.

Comment: I agree with you.  I looked at the index and found the that the level values were identical and repeated.  Where in a "normally" formed multiindex, the levels would not be repeated but the labels would be.  Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `keys` argument from `concat()` will allow your desired `groupby()` to succeed:

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index('A') for d in [d1, d2]])
df.groupby(level='A').C.sum()
```

Alternately, if `keys` needs to stay, you can get there with `reset_index()` and a repeat `groupby()`:

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index('A') for d in [d1, d2]], keys=['d1', 'd2'])
(df.groupby(level='A').sum()
   .reset_index()
   .groupby('A').sum()
)
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a work around.  I'm looking for an explanation.